# Is there a minimum voltage necessary for solenoid?

Tags: voltage

For electromagnets, is there a minimum voltage >1V required or necessary to function properly?
Example, 100mm long iron wrapped with insulated copper.
EDIT: Thanx and my apologies for not being specific enough. TO REPHRASE:
I know l will have 1 Volt to work with and have several amps. Is this enough voltage for an electromagnet 100mm long?
Neil, thanks for the note on temperatures. Also, and I can't read who it was at the moment, thanks for the note on geometry and where can I find such a discussion.

Comment: The minimal voltage is the one producing the minimal current which will produce the minimal magnetic field that is good enough for you.

Comment: a solenoid doesn't need any voltage at all, it's good existing just as it is. Now, if you want to specify that it *does* something, say generates an axial field of 0.1T, then there will be a certain current required, which will need a certain voltage. The exact values depend on the geometry of the solenoid, the wire resistance etc  etc.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear of what you're asking.  If you *edit your question* to describe what effect you're trying to get with your "minimum voltage" then we can help.  Please use quantitative terms when you can: i.e. "10 Newtons" instead of "strong" or "weak", "10 volts" (or 100, or 1) instead of "high voltage", etc.

Answer (score 4):

A solenoid, in this case, is just a coil of wire (inductor) that is implemented in such a way that it pulls or pushes a plunger to accomplish some mechanical task. The strength of the magnetic field produced by the coil depends on what the solenoid is supposed to do.

The current through each turn (wrap around the core), and the number of such turns are positively proportional to the magnetic field strength developed. In other words, more current and/or more turns equals a stronger field.

A 100mm long iron core can be wrapped with very thin enameled copper wire thousands of times. Or it could be wrapped only a few times with large diameter wire. Therefore, simply knowing the core *length* is not enough information to determine any of the solenoid's electrical characteristics.

The wire gauge principally will dictate how much current the solenoid can tolerate. Measure the coil resistance and use Ohm's law to determine how much current will be drawn for a given voltage. For example, if the coil is 2 Ω, then 5 volts will produce 2.5 amperes.

Note that temperature is important because at higher currents, the wire temperature will increase. In the inner wraps, the wire is not exposed to air and therefore cannot cool as effectively as external warps. A safe current maximum should be determined by allowable temperature increase. Also note that temperature will affect resistance, which affects current. The current drawn will therefore vary slightly as the solenoid is energized. Many commercial solenoids will specify a duty cycle, which effectively describes how long the coil can be energized and how long it needs to cool.

Generally solenoids will have a datasheet providing voltage and current ratings. If you are making your own, as I have done periodically, you will need to determine an appropriate combination of current, wire gauge, and number of turns. The required field strength is the starting point. Current and voltage available to your application (e.g. what sort of power supply is available) would be next. Number of turns and gauge of wire would be the final determination. You may need to start with a "best guess" and increase current/turns incrementally to achieve your goal.

Hopefully this gives you some information to move to the next step, whether that is providing additional information about the particular solenoid you have, or knowing what to search for from here.